# Compare query with and without score calculation

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know if it is possible to disable score calculation for `should` types of queries or maybe it is possible to have an `OR` for filter context?

ES version: 6+

For example:

this query will search matches in either `records` *OR* `voIds` and will have score calculation

```
POST customers/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "version": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "voIds": [
              78031203, ...
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "records.keyword": [
              "S3G82U", ....
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this query will filter documents that match in both `records` *AND* `voIds` and will not have score calculation. not what I need because it uses *AND*

```
POST customers/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "version": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "voIds": [
              78031203
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "records.keyword": [
              "S3G82U"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The goal for me to troubleshoot performance of the same queries with and without score. So I have first query that has score. how to write second query without score?

Thanks.

Comment: ok, looks like there it's not possible. moreover I found a resources issue. combination of network and cpu on the client side which I fixed. so such optimization doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. And I don't see much use case functionality wise. Are you seeing slowness in elasticsearch or query itself?

Comment: I think you're right. I picked it up from colleagues and to me there is some other issue as well that slows the query drastically. Started investigating now. Will share the results

Comment: ok, so it was a resources issue. combination of network and cpu on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable scoring compltely. But you can disable [query coordination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#coord). Not sure how much it helps performance wise if at all.

Comment: Thank you for idea. Looks like it just factors score behind the scenes so score is calculated.